# API Rest con Javascript y HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, api, rest

escribí este código HTML y Javascript, pero me da **error**:
**"main.js:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.js:11:2)"**

**Estoy usando Visual Studio Code y la única extensión instalada es Live Server.**

[image: HTML]

[image: Javascript]

**El código del main.js es:**

const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/'

fetch(url) /*api fetch permite interactuar con protocolos http */

.then(response => response.json()) /*convierto la respuesta a un json */

.then(data => {

```
let element = document.getElementById('elem')

element.innerHTML =

<p>${data.name} </p>; /*probé sin/con las comillas simples también y sin ; y probé con "*/

"<p>${data.order}</p>";

"<img src='${data.sprites.front_default}' />";

console.log(data) /*imprimo la promesa en la consola*/
```

})

.catch(err=>console.log(err))

**El código del HTML es:**

body
div id='elem' /div

```
script src="main.js"
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda!
Saludos
Mar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar tildes invertidas (``) cuando vayas a hacer cosas así como esa que trataste, aquí está tu código, tu lógica estaba bien, nada más tenías unos problemas de sintaxis

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let element = document.getElementById('elem')
    element.innerHTML = `
    <p>${data.name} </p>

    <p>${data.order}</p>

    <img src='${data.sprites.front_default}' />
    `
  });
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Jorge!!!!